# What is the best practice to pass a class to json?

Tags: python, json, class

Problem : I have an instance of a class and I want to pass the main infos of the class to a json compatible format. I often resort to create a to_dict method like this :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.name = name
        self.val = val

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'val': self.val,
        }
```

Then i can do

```
a = A("a_name", 5)
a.to_dict()
```

which outputs `{'name': 'a_name', 'val': 5}`

However I think it is a bit inelegant. I considered modifying the `__repr__` but I don't think it is better as I sometimes want a repr that is not a dict.

So my question : is there a better way to do this in python ?

Comment: A `to_dict` method is perfectly reasonable. I'm not sure what implementing `__repr__` would do for you, that has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: note, often, your `to_dict` can simply be `return vars(self)` although you have to be careful then not to mutate that dict unless you understand that *it is the namespace of your instance and those changes will be visible in your instance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Python standard library `json` module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) says:

> To extend this to recognize other objects,
> subclass and implement a [default()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default)
> method with another method that returns a serializable object for `o`
> if possible, otherwise it should call the superclass implementation
> (to raise [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)).

So you could do something like

```py
from json import JSONEncoder

class MyJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, A):
            return f'{{"name": "{o.name}", "value": {o.value}}}'
        return super().default(o)

# ... 

print(json.dumps(something, cls=MyJSONEncoder))
```

What I ended up doing to slightly generalize this was to say

```
    def default(self, o):
        if hasattr(o, '__json__'):
            return o.__json__()
        return super().default(o)
```

and then define a `__json__` method in the classes I wanted to specify a JSON serialization format for.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. It even works recursively! I tested it with a class where an attribute is an instance of another class. The attribute value correctly gets printed as a dict.

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives. For instance, you could make the instances iterable, and let that yield key/value pairs. Then use the dictionary constructor to take those key/value pairs:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.name = name
        self.val = val

    def __iter__(self):
        yield "name", self.name
        yield "val", self.val

a = A("Helen", 42)
d = dict(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `__dict__`,

from the example above:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, val):
        self.name = name
        self.val = val

a = A("Helen", 42)
print(a.__dict__)

# >>> {'name': 'Helen', 'val': 42}
```