# Send pathlib.Path data to FastAPI: PosixPath is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, fastapi, pydantic

I have built an API using FastAPI and am trying to send data to it from a client.

Both the API and the client use a similar Pydantic model for the data that I want to submit. This includes a field that contains a file path, which I store in a field of type pathlib.path.

However, FastAPI does not accept the submission because it apparently cannot handle the path object:

`TypeError: Object of type PosixPath is not JSON serializable`

Here's a minimal test file that shows the problem:

```
import pathlib
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient


api = FastAPI()
client = TestClient(api)

class Submission(BaseModel):
    file_path: pathlib.Path

@api.post("/", response_model=Submission)
async def add_submission(subm: Submission):
    print(subm)
    # add submission to database
    return subm


def test_add_submission():
    data = {"file_path": "/my/path/to/file.csv"}
    print("original data:", data)

    # create a Submission object, which casts filePath to pathlib.Path:
    submission = Submission(**data)  
    print("submission object:", submission)

    payload = submission.dict()
    print("payload:", payload)

    response = client.post("/", json=payload)  # this throws the error
    assert response.ok

test_add_submission()
```

When I change the model on the client side to use a string instead of a Path for `file_path`, things go through. But then I lose the pydantic power of casting the input to a Path when a Submission object is created, and then having a Path attribute with all its possibilities. Surely, there must be better way?

**What is the correct way to send a pathlib.PosixPath object to a FastAPI API as part of the payload?**

(This is Python 3.8.9, fastapi 0.68.1,  pydantic 1.8.2 on Ubuntu)

Comment: The error message means that JSON doesn't know how to turn the data into a JSON object like a string, boolean, dictionary, or list etc.  You have to specify a serialization format, or just turn it into a structure which JSON understands.  Trivially, `str(pathlib.Path(...))` produces the file name as a string; presumably that's what you actually want here.  It's not clear where in your `submission` data you have a `pathlib.Path` so you will have to figure that out yourself, or provide a [mre] which shows how this structure looks so that we can help you with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable

Comment: @tripleee The above is an MRE. It's a valid pytest file that recreates the error... I have added the call to `test_add_submission()`, so now it runs as a normal python file.

Comment: Yes, I want to keep it as a Path object. That's why I stated in the question  that I know casting it to string would solve the error but dows not help me.

Comment: Without information about what else is in `submission` we would have to investigate how `pydantic` defines it, etc. But the straightforward solution is probably to accept this as a duplicate. This unfortunately requires you to override some of the convenient functionality from `pydantic`.

Comment: @tripleee The rest of `submission` does not have any impact on the issue. The code above is a complete Python file and throws the described error. It is complete as it is. Adding other information to `submission` would delute the MRE without adding anything of value. Yes, pydantic models are that simple. As FastAPI is built on pydantic, I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution than having to build a `.toJSON()` method into a class that already provides a `.json()` out of the box (but that produces a string, and `post` does not accept it, it wants a dict).

Comment: Maybe also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66687244/what-is-the-best-practice-to-pass-a-class-to-json/66692548#66692548 ... though I agree that the ideal would be if `pydantic` offered a solution; I'm not familiar enough with it to tell you whether that is actually the case.

Comment: @CodingCat The example is fine. Have you seen how pydantic handles JSON encoding? https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/9f654a1fb2475d78731b76adf6c83c954df6d232/pydantic/json.py - this lead me to this question about extending the pydantic json encoding functionality:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311401/override-default-encoders-for-jsonable-encoder-in-fastapi .. you should be able to modify the ENCODERS_BY_TYPE and insert the path class there.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for the pointer. The pydantic-code you linked looks like `pathlib.Path` objects should already be encoded as `str`, though, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with you code is, that you first transform the pydantic model into a dict, which you then pass to the client, which uses its own json serializer and not the one provided by pydantic.

`submission.dict()` converts any pydantic model into a dict but keeps any other datatype.

With `client.post("/", json=payload)` `requests` json serializer is used, which cannot handle `pathlib.Path`.

The solution is, not to convert the pydantic model into dict first, but use the `json()` method of the pydantic model itself and pass it to the client.

```py
response = client.post("/", data=submission.json())
```

Notice that you have to change the parameter `json` to `data`.